# Ubuntu touch user manual

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I am new to ubuntu touch and I'd like to have an user manual. But I don't find one.

Can you help me getting started with ubuntu touch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some help in the [Release Notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/ReleaseNotes)

You should be able to find help in applications by pressing <kbd>F1</kbd>
*(you'll need an onscreen keyboard [image: smiley])*

Also, you should be able to use the desktop Ubuntu help, because as far as I know it might be the same in *some* areas - most likely the documentation for [12.04](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/index.html), or [13.10](https://help.ubuntu.com/13.10/ubuntu-help/index.html) - as Ubuntu Touch is still fairly new, I don't think their is much actual help or documentation for it.

<sub>*(Sadly, I don't use touch - I am not brave enough to try installing it on anything)*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You have the BQ Aquaris E4.5 Ububtu Edition manual, here's a link:

https://static-bqreaders.s3.amazonaws.com/file/Ubuntu-Aquaris_E4_5/Manual_Aquaris_E4.5_ubuntu_EN.pdf

Comment: This question was asked in December 2013, before the BQ Aquaris E4.5 for Ubuntu was available so it is unlikely that the OP is talking about an Aquaris phone, it is most likely that the the OP is using a development version of Ubuntu Touch on a Nexus phone.

Comment: Even so as the BQ phone is the only Ubuntu phone and this comes top in the search results his answer is still very useful and appreciated. You'd have thought that they would have stuck the manual on the phone somewhere.

Comment: link seems broken on my UBPorts device...