# essential apps for ubuntu touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, software-recommendation

I'm new on this forum even if I use Ubuntu since 2007. I installed Ubuntu Touch RTM stable 14.10 on my Nexus 4 to replace the previous Android completely. But I notice there area a lot of limitation byt Ubuntu Apps Store yet. 
I'd like to ask you if today there are some apps for the following essential needs:

1. Navigation (as Maps for Android): Maps is present on Ubuntu store but the navigation is not available;
2. WhatsApp like App: I don't know if Whosthere is ready to be installed for Ubuntu Touch and where sw is available to be installed;
3. a Complete User Guide or Manual: a complete documentation for ubuntu Touch;

I'm sorry maybe these questions have been asked already. If it is could you send to me the link please.

Comment: This site works best if you ask 1 question at a time. Regarding #2: dupe and some links here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/368360/whatsapp-available-for-ubuntu-phone and http://askubuntu.com/questions/442091/whatsapp-on-ubuntu-mobile Regarding #3: dupe http://askubuntu.com/questions/387930/ubuntu-touch-user-manual

Comment: Regarding #1: Google applications like maps, gmail are not open source. So it might be google that needs to provide an update for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need the answer anymore, but there might be others interested in this.

**1. Navigation:**

*uNav*

https://uappexplorer.com/app/navigator.costales

On and offline maps provided Open Street Maps and Mapzen. Features turn-by-turn voice navigation.

**2. WhatsApp-like:**

*Telegram*

https://uappexplorer.com/app/com.ubuntu.telegram

Telegram works like a charm and is very similar to WhatsApp, this one is backed by the Ubuntu Touch core dev team.

*LoquiIM*

https://open.uappexplorer.com/app/com.ubuntu.loqui.im.loqui

Third party WhatsApp client, works, but some features are yet to be implemented.

Also, there are several Webapps for WhatsApp, but since WhatsApp Web sucks a whole bunch, it's not really usable. But hey, maybe we will see an official client in the future!

**3. User Guide**

I don't think so. Just do trial and error, read some blogs, watch some videos and google your way through it. Or ask here. :)

**4. Email**

Since the question was about essentials, i will add the *Dekko* email client. The best way to write email on UT for now.

https://uappexplorer.com/app/dekko.dekkoproject

**5. What else?**

Have a look around the store:

https://uappexplorer.com/

And also the open store:

https://open.uappexplorer.com/

Also, some desktop applications can be installed, but that's to much to explain here...

Have fun with Ubuntu Touch!